# What is endpoint in REST architecture?

Tags: java, rest, endpoint

I often hear the phrase "endpoint" in the context of RESTful architecture. What is endpoint? just the method like the one in the class annotated with @Controller in Java Spring framework?

Cant actually find the exact answer to this question in google.

Comment: It's simply the URI of the call. GET /api/orders/1 is an endpoint in the API to get a single order.

Comment: ahhh I see now :) i thought it was simple, thanks!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Shouldn't that be the answer then?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel add that as the answer and I will accept that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It`s just a URI where the RESTful service can be accessed from.

E.G. https://example.com/api/products is the URI Endpoint to list all available products in the system.

Just thought I post an answer in case someone else comes across the same question.